# How to turn a router into a wifi extender/receiver and connect it to the ethernet port on my pc?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, ethernet

I made a lot of searches but I the only results I got were all about having a wifi adapter to actually get connected. I do have a wifi adapter for my old pc but I found that even the best adapter is much worse than the speed I get when I connect directly to the Ethernet.

I have an old ZTE ZXHN H108N router and it has WDS+repeater capabilities and WDS+Root capabilities. I have no idea how to make it work for my router.

As I said, I want to connect the router to the Ethernet port of my pc.

Comment: So you want the ZTE router to act as a wireless client (ie. Wireless Bridge) and you connect it to PC via ethernet? Why do you think this will be faster than using a WiFi adapter on your PC directly, same connection.

Comment: a wifi adapter uses a usb connection. My pc is quite old and usb connections usually makes it slower than it should be. If I use the Ethernet port, it doesn't affect the performance of my pc. The connection might go the same speed as the wifi adapter but it the performance won't be affected.

Comment: No offense, but I doubt the PC is the issue here, unless we are talking about an old P4 or something like that... If it's causing performance issues then you likely have a poor quality USB adapter. Regardless, it will work but you need a Wireless Bridge or Client device (like a Travel Router). The ADSL modem/router's capabilities aren't really an issue here, you just a bridge/client device that can connect to the ZTE's WiFi and bridge the network.

Comment: No offense, but I'm not accusing my PC either. And I'm here to figure out the way to do it. All you've been telling me, I already found that out on google. I came here to get an explanation of how to do it.

Comment: You need more hardware... a second router, which usually requires DD-WRT support as most routers do not have bridge capability built in, or a dedicated bridge device. If you have googled it than I don't know what you are looking for here, there isn't a trick, it is is simple and this is done all the time. Log into new router, set a static LAN IP that doesn't conflict with main router, place in Bridge/Client mode, set SSID and passcode for main WiFi, then release/renew IP on computer, that is it.

Answer (score -1):

At first, yes, wire connection is usually faster, more stable and more reliable then wireless. There are some situation where wifi can be faster, since we have standards like AC combining more wireless streams to achieve some nice speed faster then 100 Mbit, bud these devices should have 1Gb ports, so the wire is again better.

And to your problem, there should not be any problem from my perspective. If your internet come into wan (DSL) port, enable dhcp, and connect your pc to lan port.

Comment: Thanks. But how do I do that? I see my dhcp is already enabled. How do I bridge the connections?

Comment: I think you have to better explain your real situation. PC will be connected to the ZTE lan port, how can u connect internet to the ZTE? The ZTE is adsl modem, that meas, it expect internet over dsl link to the dsl port, then internet is shared on the lans and wifi, if properly configured. Do u have internet coming over dsl to this device?

Comment: No, I don't have dsl on this device. It's too far from the dsl port in my house. That's why I want to make it into a wifi receiver.

Comment: @Ashfaaq Ah... I am understanding now. Chances are you CANNOT do it with this router. Most DSL modem/routers are hard coded to only be APs for the WAN (DSL) and they are not full-blown "routers". You will need different equipment.

Comment: @Ashfaaq so you have some AP in your house, and u want this ZTE to connect to this wifi and then share its internet connection via lan ports of the ZTE?

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do. I guess I won't be able to do it with my old router as it is not even supported by DD_WRT